# JavaScript Weather APIKey issue

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-401, weather-api, jsapi

Code 401

[image]

JS Code

[image]

My API key is working properly in the browser. But I can't get it in the Live server.  It shows 401 error as unauthorized.  I turned off my firewall too and also I can't get my results. My console says that same error only.

```js
const apiKey = "5926da84fa5ddbb8fb12992a5d7b7585";
const apiUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=chennai";
async function checkWeather() {
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl + '&appid=${apiKey}');
  var data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);

}

checkWeather();
```

Comment: Please don't show api keys online, people can steal them and you should probably change your key asap.

Comment: Typo.  You're using a plain string instead of a template literal.  The error message is showing you that the resulting URL contains *literally* `${apiKey}` instead of replacing it with the actual value.

Comment: Oh Thank you so much. I will follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 const apiKey = "5926da84fa5ddbb8fb12992a5d7b7585";
        const apiUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=chennai";  

        async function checkWeather() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}&appid=${apiKey}`);
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching weather data:", error);
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("checkWeatherButton").addEventListener("click", checkWeather);
    </script>
```

```html
 <button id="checkWeatherButton">Check Weather</button>
```

you have a single quote but you are using a template literal so you can't use a single quote

so it should be

```js
const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}&appid=${apiKey}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

`const response=await fetch(apiUrl+'&appid=${apiKey}');`

Use backticks instead of single or double quotes,

> const response=await fetch(apiUrl+`&appid=${apiKey}`);